# Changing colors of variables on a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the color for the individual 'Years' variable on this plot. So far I have this code:

```
x <- ggplot(elect, aes(x = `Congressional Spending`, y = `United States VEP Midterm Turnout Rate`, color = Year)) +
     geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm, col = 'purple', size = 0.5)
```

[image]

I also tried using:

```
scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "yellow",
                               "blue", "orange",
                               "green", "black"))
```

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to have a look at the data. The problem is most likely that your variable `year` is a `double`. So you need to call `as.factor()` in your code (see below):

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=carb, color=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","green","blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>